# HDIV : skipping parameters validation

Tags: httprequest, hdiv

Is there any way to skip request parameters validation in HDIV framework ?

We have many pages in our application with so many parameters and we can't declare all of them as startParameters.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define startParameter as a Java Pattern. So, you can exclude all parameters from validation, for example:

```
<hdiv:startParameter>.*</hdiv:startParameter>
```

In this case you are disabling the integrity validation of all request parameters.
Is this what you want to do? And why?

Comment: That's what I'm seeking.
It's because we have so many parameters and I don't know all of them.
So I'm afraid if I try to control the integrity of these parameters something goes wrong.

Comment: It's actually `<hdiv:startParameters>.*</hdiv:startParameters>`